# Extension for Azure Devops and output

Tags: azure-devops, output, azure-devops-extensions

I'm developper of a private custom extension usable in Azure Devops.

I have a problematic around the output of task.json in our extension and wonder if you can help to clarify / resolve the problematic.

1-What works.

I have created a release with 2 step :
First step, execute my extension
Second Step, retrieve output variable (sorry for the naming of the task, I'm in testing mode)
[image]

Our task.json execute a script named vm.ps1

[image]

In this vm.ps1 script, I have a piece of code to set the value of the variable $VirtualMachineId:

[image]

This value is then retrieve with the second step of the release, azure powershell inline script :

[image]

The result is diplayed in the log :
[image]

My value is retrieved, the goal is accomplish.

2-What doesn’t work : Implement in the task.json

Now, if I want to fully implement this variable in the product, I need to add this one in the output section of our task.json :

[image]

So, the UI of our interface will be display in the output section like the example below ( do not be disturb to not see VirtualMachineId in the below image, it is an illustration image):
[image]

I run another time my release, as I can see in the log of the extension execution, the variable is set with appropriate value.

[image]

Then the Azure inline script execute and the value is **empty** :
[image]

To resume:
If I declare the variable in the output section of the task json, I can't retrieve the value or the value is empty.
Does anybody here have an idea of what I do wrong ?

Thanks to have take time to read me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the output variable's value of a task. You need to set a reference name for the following task to refer to the output variable.

For example: **Download secure file** task has an output variable (`secureFilePath`) . In order the following task to refer to its output variable. The reference name needs to be defined(eg. `myFile`).

[image]

Then in the following tasks. You can refer to the output variable(`secureFilePath`) by `$(myFile.secureFilePath)`

[image]

Hope above helps!

Comment: Hello, thanks you for your help. One of my collegue point me to this direction. You answered correctly to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how to pass variables between tasks (in `adhoc scripting` ):

1. Task one (set new variable):

```yaml
steps:
- powershell: 'Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"'
  displayName: 'set_variable'
```

2. Task two (get variable from the scope):

```yaml
steps:
- powershell: 'Write-Host $(testvar)'
  displayName: 'print_variable'
```

This way your variable is accessible in all tasks under same job execution.

Output variables are meant to be a way for passing the value between task. If you need to pass variable between `jobs`, just use `dependencies` with `output variables`.

Here I made a sample stage that:

- contains 2 jobs `A` & `B`
- creates output variable named `testvar`
- passes output variable between stages with use of dependencies
- displays variable

```yaml
trigger:
- master

jobs:
- job: A
  steps:
  - powershell: 'Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;isOutput=true;]testvalue"'
    displayName: 'set_variable'  
    name: "Setter"
- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  variables:
    # map the output variable from A into this job
    varFromA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['Setter.testvar'] ]
  steps:
  - script: echo $(varFromA)
```

If it doesn't solve problem.. It means I do not understand your use case. Could you elaborate more?

Here you can see some useful documentation.

[GitHub Notes](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/docs/preview/outputvariable.md)
[Microsoft Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch)

Comment: Thanks you to take time to give your feedback.
I am able to set outputs variable and display them.
The problem is when I set them as output in the task.json of my extension, after that they are empty :(
In other word and if I understand you correctly you repduced the "What works" part of my question :)